# Message Broker Node output terminal with multiple connections

Tags: ibm-integration-bus

What happens when you connect multiple connections to a single output terminal on a node.

I cannot find any IBM documentation on this but the toolkit does not stop me from doing it.

[image]

This is just one example but I would like to know the behavior in general when you do this to any node, not just the input node...

I know there are flow order nodes that could be used and I know that you can put nodes in line with each other.

What I'm interested is the IBM documented behavior about what happens when you do this and any other information that you can provide me on this from your experience etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The manual section that explains the behavior [is here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmbhelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/ac02260_.htm).  From the manual:

> You can connect a single output terminal of one node to the input
>   terminal of more than one node (this is known as fan-out). If you do
>   this, the same message is propagated to all target nodes, but you have
>   no control over the order in which the subsequent paths through the
>   message flow are executed (except with the FlowOrder node).
>
> You can also connect the output terminal of several nodes to a single
>   node input terminal (this is known as fan-in). Again, the messages
>   that are received by the target node are not received in any guaranteed order.

Make sure you have the version of the Infocenter that matches your version of Broker! The above is from the v7.0 Infocenter.  The Information Centers for several versions of WebSphere Message Broker are [available here](http://ibm.co/sAKgpu) in online and downloadable formats.

Comment: Thanks! I was looking all through that documentation and I could not find that page! Exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Glad it helped! I'm more of an MQ specialist so I'm always happy when I can answer a WMB question. Even better if I can actually answer it correctly!  ;-)

Comment: I'm going to add a note here that I found out while implementing this: If the path WMB decides to go down first throws an error, the second path will not be executed. This has the same behavior as a flow order node, just that it does not guarantee order. The first path cannot throw an error, or else the second one will not execute.

Comment: I think it may even go beyond what you describe.  My understanding (and I'm not a WMB specialist so this may be wrong) is that a failure on any path will cause a rollback on all paths and then traversal of the failure path.  The implication is that if the second path fails, the first path will roll back any transactional activity *even though it may have otherwise executed properly.*

Comment: That does sounds like it makes sense, since I think that is what happens for a flow order node too... Would be nice if it mentioned this issue on that page of the documentation. Although I'm not sure if something like writing to a trace file would be rolled back?

Comment: No, only transactional activity can be rolled back.  Things happening outside of syncpoint such as traces or logs will survive.